# Strategy Design Pattern : Calling constructor of behavioral class

Tags: java, design-patterns

I am going through the book `Head First Design Pattern`, and the first design pattern that I encountered was Strategy Design Pattern. I found it fairly easy to understand and implement, but while implementing I am facing one problem that I don't know how can we call a 'Parameterized Constructor of the Behavioral class'.

A snapshot from the book :

[image]

Here I am talking about how to call the constructor of `FlyWithWings, Quack etc` classes.

I will give an example of Strategy Design Pattern to understand it in a better way :

```
//Strategy Interface
public interface CompressionStrategy {
  public void compressFiles(ArrayList<File> files);
}

public class ZipCompressionStrategy implements CompressionStrategy {
public void compressFiles(ArrayList<File> files) {
    //using ZIP approach
  }
}
public class RarCompressionStrategy implements CompressionStrategy {
public void compressFiles(ArrayList<File> files) {
    //using RAR approach
  }
}
public class CompressionContext {
private CompressionStrategy strategy;
  //this can be set at runtime by the application preferences
  public void setCompressionStrategy(CompressionStrategy strategy) {
    this.strategy = strategy;
  }

  //use the strategy
  public void createArchive(ArrayList<File> files) {
    strategy.compressFiles(files);
  }
}

public class Client {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    CompressionContext ctx = new CompressionContext();
    //we could assume context is already set by preferences
    ctx.setCompressionStrategy(new ZipCompressionStrategy());
    //get a list of files...
    ctx.createArchive(fileList);
  }
}
```

So in the above example `RarCompressionStrategy` and `ZipCompressionStrategy` are the behavioral class. So can it be possible to trigger their parametrized constructor class of these behavioral classes from `CompressionContext` class?

Comment: I am not seeing a single parameterized constructor.

Comment: @LucianovanderVeekens That is just an example, I am asking if we have a parameterized constructor then HOW can it be called?

Comment: `ctx.setCompressionStrategy(new ZipCompressionStrategy(someImaginaryParam));`

Comment: In real life, the creation of implementing classes is best to delegate to a Dependency Injection library.

Comment: @Fildor That's from Client class right. What if we need to pass the same data from Client to CompressionContext as well as ZipCompressionStrategy, then what will be the most efficient way?

Comment: Since you instantiate the Strategy outside the context, you'd have to pass that data to the context *and* the Strategy. If the Context had some Factory method, that took this data and constructed the strategy for you, then you could pass it along inside that factory method.

Comment: If the context holds some params that are needed by the strategy to do its job, then the signature of the method of the strategy should be `compressFiles(List<File> files, SomeParam someParam)` and the context should pass the param when calling the strategy. Or even maybe `compressFiles(List<File> files, CompressionContext context)`. There are plenty of different ways to solve the same problem of course, and all will probably be as afficient. Efficiency isn't the concern here. Design is.

Comment: @JBNizet Yeah this sounds good to me.

Answer (score 2):

```
public class ZipCompressionStrategy implements CompressionStrategy {
   public ZipCompressionStrategy (String param1, String param2) {
         // do something
   }
   public void compressFiles(ArrayList<File> files) {
        //using ZIP approach
   }
}
public class RarCompressionStrategy implements CompressionStrategy {
public void compressFiles(ArrayList<File> files) {
    //using RAR approach
  }
}
```

and then

```
ctx.setCompressionStrategy(new ZipCompressionStrategy(param1, param2)) //with params
ctx.setCompressionStrategy(new RarCompressionStrategy()) //without params
```